# Google Scripts getCalendarsByName to return calendars with similar names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, wildcard

I'd like to perform a function that allows me to interrogate only google calenders that have a particular character in, namely "#".

I know that the function CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName returns an array of calendars, so I was hoping I could use this function along with wildcards to return the calendars I want. I got some advice on using wild cards from here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/gmf6ewpjH4g/

Here's the code so far:

```
function Test() {  
  var pattern = /.*#.*/;
  var calendarsz = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(pattern); 
  Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendarsz.length);
};
```

But it's returning no calendars at all. Any suggestions on how to use wildcards with this function, or alternative approaches to returning only calendars with particular characters will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getCalendarsByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename) method does not support searching with wild card

> getCalendarsByName(name)
>
> Gets all calendars with a given name that the user owns or is subscribed to. Names are not case-sensitive.

```
// Gets the public calendar named "US Holidays".
var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('US Holidays');
Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);
```

> Parameters
>
> Name   - the calendar name

For that matter the Google Calendar API doesn't support it either so that is not going to work at all.   You are going to have to download them all and search them locally probably using getAllCalendars